# how make a generic method in a abstract parent class for implementation typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, entity-component-system

What will be the best and (proper) approach to make this in TypeScript.
`$Foo.getInstance('uid')` should return a `FooInstance` based on implementations?

I want in the abstact class `Entity` a method to get a instance from a pool,
for return the implemented `EntityInstance`.

```js
abstract class Entity {
    abstract Instance: Partial<typeof EntityInstance>;
    instances: { [uid: string]: EntityInstance } = {};
    getInstance (uid: string ) {
        return this.instances[uid]
    }
}
abstract class EntityInstance {
    prop='';
}

class Foo extends Entity {
    Instance = FooInstance // @implementation
}
class FooInstance extends EntityInstance {

}


const $Foo = new Foo();
// need return InstanceType<FooInstance>
const instance = $Foo.getInstance('uid');
```

So example here:
`const instance = $Foo.getInstance('uid')` should be a `FooInstance`;
But it actually a `EntityInstance` thats correct !
[image]

so i try change this method `getInstance` to something like this.

```js
    getInstance <t=this>(uid: string ): InstanceType<this['Instance']> {
        return this.instances[uid]
    }
```

It working !:) but make some error type.
Am noob with ts documentations, what change i can made to make this logic work fine.
I know ts is powerful, but am not sure how to make this work fine for intelisence in my ide.

[image]

---

minimal reproductive demo [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFEDsBcEtoJ4DpoGcAeAoAhgI1dAE7YDG0oJANtqqhDPAqAN6ajujABUXohApgDNQ0APahsoAA6UArgHNYkUP3TR%20kACb9NoAAZQ4iAJKQC2SCX57QXYGw54CxMqHn9yp85f4AKAJQAXKAACtiEcNiUADyIUvyiwoaMXtAWVgB8ANwOHNy8ABaiAO6gALbYANb8IgWwdO6Q-ISwJKAA-Ox2uaBK3laowcygANqysJrBzkryALrBySZmaT6gAL6gALwsazlrOPhEpORUNHSLCKnpNawc7AD694KiogCMm697OZiYILKozWkckUkBQGEwp1ooAAYi8VGoNJpzgxECweldVttYaIMVYcncQKAABIlXoUCxuDy1eqgQSEURlWo1KThDTkYqwIqyciwMoyfhlNnUugFZr8HogPorAZDUbjSagaaQObBbG4mobbbMXaYfaQuhq5bXeHqLTIoyXI2rW4cR7PUQAJk2Dr2PxAqikogiOlpXqZEiksAhomWoAAJNitqAmqVsQEchGXkgpddUCMAORlBAAVQm6dmUZj4exSHV8d%20wFQDP4xVFAl6ymgouk9PkxDKSGDoaz6qjidEyatAwzWdzmnzWU4YFw-BI2H%20NWKzLOoFwTH7ABoycULORBLJKJQRAh4voLuq9Jge0P%20Eg7S9PlfLf1b-fHVkgA)
i want `myInstance.__foo2;` not produce error.

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of errors with plain text versions when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NalRpw), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: Right now, I can't understand why you expect a `FooInstance` to come out; the implementation is indexing into the empty `instances` object and returning `undefined`.  That's neither a `FooInstance` nor an `EntityInstance`.  And the type `Partial<typeof EntityInstance>` is strange; it doesn't have to be a class constructor at all.  And `InstanceType<FooInstance>` is also not really sensible.  If you could make your example code actually do what you are asking about at runtime, I could help with the typing.  But right now I can't follow what the intent is, other than the need for `this` types.

Comment: thanks @jcalz , it a minimal reproductible for me, but sometime is hard to transform complex thing in a simple thing. Is this help, i made a another version with more generic work ?  `tinyurl.com/yzk5j7nh`

Comment: so i want a wayt to make `myInstance.__foo2;` working

Comment: i update the prost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try changing the typings in `Entity` to the following:

```
abstract class Entity {
    abstract Instance: new () => EntityInstance;

    instances: Record<string,
        InstanceType<this["Instance"]> | undefined
    > = {};
}
```

The `Instance` property is a [constructor](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) that returns an `EntityInstance` (or a subtype of it).  And the `instances` property type depends on the type of `Instance`; by using [polymorphic `this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types), we are saying for any subclass of `Entity` the `instances` property will depend on the type of `Instance` in the same subclass.

This gives you the behavior you're looking for, at least for the example code:

```
class Foo extends Entity {
    Instance = FooInstance;
}
class FooInstance extends EntityInstance {
    __foo2 = 2;
}

const $Foo = new Foo();
$Foo.instances['myUid'] = new $Foo.Instance();

const myInstance = $Foo.instances['myUid'];
myInstance.__foo2; // okay
```

Note that polymorphic `this` types can be a bit of a pain to work with inside the subclasses themselves:

```
class Foo extends Entity {
    Instance = FooInstance;

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.instances.abc = new FooInstance(); // error!
        this.instances.abc = new this.Instance(); // error!
    }

}
```

I'm not sure if you need to do something like this, but trying to set a property on `this.instances` inside `Foo` fails because the compiler doesn't know what `this` will be if someone comes along and subclasses `Foo`.  It treats `this` like an unspecified generic type and is not really able to verify that any particular value is assignable to it.  In such cases you might need to use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to suppress errors.

---

Another approach is to make `Entity` a [generic class](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-classes) where the type parameter `T` corresponds to the particular subtype of `EntityInstance` in subclasses:

```
abstract class Entity<T extends EntityInstance> {
    abstract Instance: new () => T;
    instances: Record<string, T | undefined> = {};
}
```

Any particular subclass needs to specify what `T` should be (which is a bit redundant), but then everything works... both inside and outside the subclass:

```
class Foo extends Entity<FooInstance> {
    Instance = FooInstance;
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.instances.abc = new FooInstance(); // okay
        this.instances.abc = new this.Instance(); // okay
    }
}

myInstance.__foo2;  // still okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAFA9gGwJ5jQJxgAsBLeAFRKiQG8AoJBpEAIygBc8E2l4MQoqAUWBtibLDXqNpLdp3jcAksHYhgiAFxJgEAO5IAFAEokAXgB8SYaPHLV6iAG5aU6Q2Iq2axFC0AlCHh8ABMAHjkPAHMAGlc3aTsvBzIsGAhQtkoAbQAiRO8IHIBdSwAfJABXYGCIADMPCGC46UtTGgBfZ2l2uNkOLh4+ASsRMSx8h0l4hgB9Gdq0NABGMyQlrsZOl2kAeh2KqAg8JBgMCsiPADo2KAAPON5+KgAxRaQIW7YIaqFR8SnphNEKtXmggU5ttMgp48BUFPhjADpowoBU0nhjBtkQxMsQoJcPPYfJcWPBVjp9KDwZikHt3ng8PgAITNaa4-GEpLE0nkvRIdmXalGRy0nb0xl4FnInpxHrSR7DKmeArvT7fYK-GzjZWTOjIuYLNAAJlWRqxSBl8rQniQABJQbzKYtMXF7YsCTqfFkAORgLAAVWIwW9RUddtBgs9EBdD2t7CQfvBqzdaA9ROgPr9geDRXNiajlwNi3WcXz6cL80WZpcMtAkFgCGQAHFvkdSEimKx+gpBk8RlrQmRVV8fv2xuDLHrpn15Eoo1oKYYTBYkGRnKz3FHfEgAkE8GEIsAYqukOUqjV6jpgq0Oua5YwZwMFZrx1GO9Ii8tViXuuvdvtDmOU5ziuG57geIYXjeD4Rw1MdxFCJV00nDckCTNokK5CFkWhOQ4TYBETCnbEkFRdEXRInFKDTLD8R5NpF0wgoaTpNAAGsQCwVDpAFTkCjo5gyQYvkBSFEVWI4rjpVlOIIL7JjJhg9UX1sN9iLcT8TTaatukhBhcO4FMw1BCjGBTGj+MzAMgxDMNzLEvSeDjbgyyw5MIz4hwoCs7MQzzbVy0-H9GFcgoK0NataHaIA)

Comment: Oki thanks you so much @jcalz for this quality doc!, very great explanation and proposition. So experimented a lot with both and i retain de last solutions because is more near my current need and littlebit more readable ! I just have a little one more issue with last solution. If you are ok to take a look on a more complex example. Am not sure why i get error there and am not enough experimented. Just if you have time, i will keep searching in the doc :)    `tinyurl.com/4f39wte4`